# How to set concurrency value with min and max limits in @JMSListner via property file in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jms

I am trying to set the max and min limits for concurrency in @JMSListner annotation via property file since I don't want it to be hardcoded. Sample code is below

@JmsListener(destination = "${DESTINATION.QUEUE}",
concurrency = "${maxConcurrentConsumers}")

However what I see when my application starts is that it sets default consumers as 1 which means it somehow does not able to understand the expression.

Is there any way to do it so that it reads it from property file.

Any help would be appreciated.